# Sharedpreferences aren't working, default values

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

My app has a lot of checkboxes in it, a spinner, edittext and a button. When I choose an item from the spinner and then enter a certain value and hit a button, a certain checkbox text changes. Now I added shared preferences and I have two problems.

First problem is that when I try to use sharedpreferences the app crashes (as soon as I start the activity containing these sharedpreferences).

```
private String getItemQuantity(String key){
    SharedPreferences itemQuantitySP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sp1 = "sp1";
    return itemQuantitySP.getString(key, sp1);
}
private void saveItemQuantity(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences itemQuantitySP = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = itemQuantitySP.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Saving sharedpreferences:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(quantityEditText.getText().toString()) == 250)
{
    cb4.setText("Elaborate Totem (" + item1 + "/250)");
    saveItemQuantity("cb4", cb4.getText().toString());
    cb4.setChecked(true);
}
... //REST OF THE CODE
```

Getting sharedpreferences:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bifrost);

    getItemQuantity("cb4");
... //REST OF THE CODE
```

Second problem is that I have a lot of checkboxes and setting default value for every single one of them would be very time consuming. So is there a way to simply read the default value from XML? As you can see, for now, I created a new variable called sp1 and set it as the default value, but ofcourse I want to get rid of that.

Logcat file:

```
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.matthewstudios.gw2legendary/com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost.getItemQuantity(Bifrost.java:849)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost.onCreate(Bifrost.java:152)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    ... 11 more
06-27 16:31:49.391: E/fb4a(:<default>):MmsConfig(13225): MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting
```

Part of the code:

```
public void submitQuantityButton (View v){
    final Spinner sItems = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Context context = this;
    final CheckBox cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    final CheckBox cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
    final CheckBox cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
    final CheckBox cb7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
    final CheckBox cb9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
    final CheckBox cb10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox10);
    final CheckBox cb11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox11);
    final CheckBox cb12 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox12);
    final CheckBox cb13 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox13);
    final CheckBox cb15 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox15);
    final CheckBox cb16 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox16);
    final CheckBox cb17 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox17);
    final CheckBox cb18 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox18);
    final CheckBox cb25 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox25);
    final CheckBox cb27 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox27);
    final CheckBox cb28 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox28);
    final CheckBox cb29 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox29);
    final CheckBox cb30 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox30);
    final CheckBox cb31 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox31);
    final CheckBox cb33 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox33);
    final CheckBox cb34 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox34);
    final CheckBox cb35 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox35);
    final CheckBox cb36 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox36);
    final CheckBox cb37 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox37);

    //WRONG VALUE ERROR
    final AlertDialog.Builder wrongValueBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    wrongValueBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
    wrongValueBuilder.setMessage("The value you entered is too high!");
    wrongValueBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    //EMPTY TEXT ERROR
    final AlertDialog.Builder emptyETextErrorBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setMessage("Please enter a value before pressing this button");
    emptyETextErrorBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

            final int position = sItems.getSelectedItemPosition();
            EditText quantityEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            switch (position){
            case 0:
                AlertDialog.Builder spinnerErrorBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setMessage("Please choose an item from the list above and then enter a certain value");
                spinnerErrorBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog spinnerError = spinnerErrorBuilder.create();
                spinnerError.show();
                break;
            case 1:
                String item1 = quantityEditText.getText().toString();
                if (item1.matches(""))
                {
                    AlertDialog emptyETextError = emptyETextErrorBuilder.create();
                    emptyETextError.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(quantityEditText.getText().toString()) <= 250)
                    {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(quantityEditText.getText().toString()) == 250)
                        {
                            cb4.setText("Elaborate Totem (" + item1 + "/250)");
                            saveItemQuantity("cb4", cb4.getText().toString());
                            cb4.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cb4.setText("Elaborate Totem (" + item1 + "/250)");
                            saveItemQuantity("cb4", cb4.getText().toString());
                            cb4.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Could you post error which you get when using `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: post the original code

Comment: Posted the logcat file, still wondering about the default values tho. @blackbelt do you mean actually the whole java code? Because it's really really long

Comment: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String. You can not cast a Boolean to String. Look for the row per the cast happens

Comment: Check my original post, I added a part of my code. I can't find where could be the problem. Probably this: cb4.getText().toString() but I don't know how to do it any other way

Comment: post the whole logcat

Comment: which one is SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the first one I posted (saving sharedpreferences)

Comment: Probably you put a boolen with the same key inside sharedprferences

Comment: Yes! That was it, the app doesn't crash anymore, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacktrace, and the 3 following lines, shows where is the problem:

```
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
06-27 16:31:44.782: E/AndroidRuntime(13139):    at com.example.gw2legendary.Bifrost.getItemQuantity(Bifrost.java:849)
```

So you have a problem in the file Bifrost.java, at line 849, in the `getItemQuantity()` method. And it corresponds to the call to `getString()` method. It's really interesting looking at the 3 lines and try to understand how you can get all these informations, because you'll have to do the same each time you have an exception in your code.

What I can suppose is that the value you try to get from the `SharedPreferences` has been saved as `Boolean`, and you try to get it as a `String`, so you have this ClassCastException. Just revise the value you saved in the SharedPreferences with that key.

To have more information, try to learn how to debug your application and use breakpoints to check the values of the variables at a moment of the execution. Breakpoints allow you to stop the execution exactly where you want and look for the state and values of all the variables. Debugging with an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans is really easy and can help you in a lot of situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It explains a lot but I am not sure how to "revise" the value with the key, I'm pretty new to this so I'm not completely sure what exactly that means. Could you tell me?

Comment: For example, before `return itemQuantitySP.getString(key, sp1);`, you can add a line like: `Map<String, ?> map = itemQuantitySP.getAll();` and then get the value with the key with `Object value = map.get(key);`. Then you can check the value with the debugger or printing it. You'll have to find in the code where you are saving a boolean with this key in the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a bit confused about everything right here since I'm a beginner but I'll do some more research and clear things up :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious what the error is from reading the stacktrace:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

And yes you can read default values from an XML file, read about arrays.xml and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray here

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you tell me how would I approach fixing my code? I'm pretty much still a beginner and I do understand what the error is saying but I can't really find the main source and how to fix it

Comment: In your logcat, after the 2 lines you added in your question, you have a full stacktrace. A line in this stacktrace should refer to your code, and this line should include the exact line number in your code where the error occurs. Then you can deduce the code that gives you the exception and try to understand why. You can also add the full stacktrace and indicate the line of your code so that we can know where to search.

Comment: I think I get how the stacktrace works now but I can't really point a finger to which line of the code exactly it affects, I posted the whole stacktrace tho. Thanks a lot for explaining it